# ¿Que es npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0 y como actualizarlo?

Tags: nodejs, npm, gatsby

Estoy tratando de generar un proyecto de gatsby y al momento de correr el: **npm install -g gatsby-cli** me aparece lo siguiente: **npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.*** verifique mi versión de node y es la **v14.15.1** y la de npm que es la: **8.5.5**. De ante mano muchas gracias, a quien me lea y ayude.

Comment: Te está diciendo claramente que _uuid_ está en la versión 3.4.0 y que debés actualizar a una versión >= 7.

Comment: Copiado, copiado.